# is it possible to link firebase auth to the real-time Database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Is there a way i can do something like the following.

[image: this the sample model of my firebase real-time database]

The thing is, I can't figure out how to connect it on my authentication which contains my userIDs.

Can someone explain or give me an example?

*Edit*: code from comment on an answer:

```
Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString()); 
Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(edt2.getText().toString()); 
Integer result = num1+num2; 
String data = Date+result; 
DateView.setText("Date Computed: " + Date + Hrs +"\n \n Computed Result: "+ result); 
HashMap<String, Integer> userMap = new HashMap<>(); 
userMap.put(Hrs, result); 
rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
reference = rootNode.getReference("Users").child("UserID").child("Logs");
reference.push().child(Date).setValue(userMap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to write the data under a node that uses the UID as the key. So the first step is to determine the UID of the current user:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

And then you use that to write to the database:

```
rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(); 
reference = rootNode.getReference("Users").child(uid).child("Logs");
reference.setValue(userMap);
```

This code matches with the JSON you show in your questions. If you want to auto-generate unique child nodes under `Logs`, you can use `push()` to do so.

Comment: oh gee you're a life saver, I can't thibk of any solutions, I'll try this later

Answer (score 2):

Store the users in your database when user has done the sign up process.
i.e

```
users
   userId1
      name XYZ
      email XYZ
      ........
    userId2
      name XYZ
      email XYZ
      ........
```

Comment: yes that is what it should look like in realtime database, but i don't know the right code and the proper way to store it

Comment: could you please elaborate more so that I can help you

Comment: Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(edt1.getText().toString());
 Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(edt2.getText().toString());
 Integer result = num1+num2;
String data = Date+result;
DateView.setText("Date Computed: " + Date + Hrs +"\n \n Computed Result: "+ result);
 HashMap<String, Integer> userMap = new HashMap<>();
   userMap.put(Hrs, result);
                rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                reference = rootNode.getReference("Users").child("UserID").child("Logs");
                reference.push().child(Date).setValue(userMap);

Comment: i have that line that can produce a database tree like this:

Comment: get the userid from
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
instead of calculation date etc.